# Does local host refer to your own machine?

Tags: php, mysql

When I run PHPmyAdmin its in the form: domain/localhost/phypmyadmin. What does localhost refer to? The files that I want to import are in domain but I still cannot import them using the load local statement.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? What sort of files do you want to import and for what purpose?

Comment: What do you mean by "load local statement"?

Comment: I simply want to load my data stored in text files into a database. I am just very confused of how to import the files. When I ran the system mysql on my remote linux machine, it was very easy as I could just load the data via. user@remote:~/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Localhost is typically your machine.  I'm not sure what you're wanting to do with files.  If you're running Linux, connecting to Localhost will connect through the loopback interface in most distributions (not your main Ethernet interface).  I'd look to see what interface your server is bound to, and adjust your address properly.

To answer the comment above, generally MySQL Servers are bound to the loopback interface making them accessible only on that local machine.  If you need to import files from a remote machine, you would have to copy the file to the server, and run the command locally.

If that's still problematic, PHPMyAdmin has an import feature.  If you can access PHPMyAdmin, you can import your file through that interface (If your file is large, you might have to kick up the max file upload settings.  I'm not positive, but I'm pretty sure it's a PHP setting.)

Answer (score 0):

I dont completely understand the problem you are having.
but here are somethings you should know

- localhost refers to the system itself. So in this case the server running phpmyadmin and mysql (it can also be accessed by 127.0.0.1 instead of the term localhost
- You can access phpmyadmin on a remote system if u have its public ip and open the firewall ports, and also allow phpmyadmin to work on remote systems
- If you have text .sql files in a remote system you should be able to import them via phpmyadmin only if you are able to use phpmyadmin on that system

If i understand your problem correct, this is what u need to do

**Method 1:**
Transfer the text files to the server running the mysql and phpmyadmin then use it to upload on to mysql

**Method 2:**
Enable phpmyadmin to work for remote users, find your public ip and open all ports on your firewall

Comment: phpadmin is running on a remote machine and I am accessing it from locahost. Then why can't mysql find LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'user@remote_name:~/blah.txt'? when I run it in the sql window?

Comment: I see that I am running root@localhost

Comment: in myslq root@localhost means that you are using the user root... from the ip/system termed as localhost
and when u say accessing it from localhost .. it doesnt give me much....are u RDPing??? or from accesing from your own system (ie it wouldnt say localhost)
stop using the CLI and load the txt file via phpmyadmin it would be much easier...

Comment: The reason why I want to write the sql file is that I don't have access rights to php.ini